# Android resources linking failed

Tags: android, linker

I made a little game using RPG maker that I want to put on the play store, which forces me to use this Android studio, which I don't understand at all.

When trying to create a signed .apk file via android studio, I received an error message saying: "Generate Signed APK: Errors while building APK. You can find the errors in the 'Messages' view."

And here are the errors. What can I do?

This is the copy of the screen I have:

[image: This is the copy of the screen I have]

and the second one:

[image: and the second one]